# How to compute this limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I compute this limit?

$$\lim_{\{a,x\}\to \{1,0\}} \,  (1-a) x \coth ((1-a) x)$$

```
Limit[  x (-a + 1) Coth[(-a + 1) x], {a, x} -> {1, 0}]
```

Comment: It returns `1` in Mathematica v12.1.1.0

Comment: So does version 12.0.

Comment: In addition to the multivariate limit that you show evaluating to `1` the nested limit `Limit[x (-a + 1) Coth[(-a + 1) x], {a -> 1, x -> 0}]` also evaluates to `1`. The documentation indicates that the last change to `Limit` was with version 11.2

Comment: @flinty Mine is 10. So, this is the reason. Thanks.